# Make asp.net razor template without view or controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

I have some code repetition across 5 pages, its a widget type of thing that's only needed sometimes. I want to make a "widget"-like cshtml template, without a model or view because it doesnt need any external data. I just need to "import" it into some places on my pages.

I am aware of tag helpers, but this is very HTML heavy and its annoying to have to type it in strings and stuff. I'd rather have nice syntax highlighting.

Comment: Have you tried a [Partial View](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-2.2)?

Comment: @Jasen this is exactly what i needed, feel free to turn that into an answer! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Partial View without declaring a model or backing action.

**_Privacy.cshtml**

```
<div class="gdpr">
    <h2>Privacy</h2>
    <p>...</p>
</div>
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
...
<partial name="_Privacy" />
```

The prefixed underscore ("_") is naming convention for partial views.

Docs:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-2.2

> Partial Tag Helper The Partial Tag Helper requires ASP.NET Core 2.1 or
>   later.
>
> The Partial Tag Helper renders content asynchronously and uses an
>   HTML-like syntax:
>
> ```
> <partial name="_PartialName" />
> ```
>
> When a file extension is present, the Tag Helper references a partial view that must be in the same folder as the markup file calling the partial view:
>
> ```
> <partial name="_PartialName.cshtml" />
> ```
>
> The following example references a partial view from the app root. Paths that start with a tilde-slash (~/) or a slash (/) refer to the app root:
>
> **Razor Pages**
>
> ```
> <partial name="~/Pages/Folder/_PartialName.cshtml" />
> <partial name="/Pages/Folder/_PartialName.cshtml" />
> ```
>
> **MVC**
>
> ```
> <partial name="~/Views/Folder/_PartialName.cshtml" />
> <partial name="/Views/Folder/_PartialName.cshtml" />
> ```
>
> The following example references a partial view with a relative path:
>
> ```
> <partial name="../Account/_PartialName.cshtml" />
> ```